# Docker with git worktree: fatal: Not a git repository

Tags: git, docker, git-worktree

I have `projects` folder that is in my `/home/my/` folder on host and mounted at `/home/user/projects` at docker container. In this folder there is git repo `/home/user/projects/repo` with additional worktree:  `/home/user/projects/repo-b` (added by `git worktree add`)

When I am tring to do any git command in `/home/user/projects/repo-b` I recive

```
fatal: Not a git repository: /home/my/projects/repo/.git/worktrees/repo-b/
```

I have tried to create link at home: `me -> user` without any progress.

Comment: Is /home/my/projects/repo-b/ a git repo on the host?

Comment: It is additional working tree. I have edited question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem was simple and stupid. My `git` in docker container was old enough not to support `worktree` functionality. 
So updating `git` and creating simlink to user folder solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing a directory which is not mounted inside a container is a big challenge (so do symbolic links). Whenever possible, avoid this kind of usage so that it won't cause confusion.

If you are going to use it anyway, try to mount both of the directories.